# Passing a Class as Variable C#

Tags: c#, class, variables

I need some help, hope it is doable.

I would like to pass a Class as a variable in C#.

This is my code so you can see what I am trying to do:

```
object shClass;
switch ((cbxType.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Value)
{
    case "articles":
            shClass = ArticlesClass;
            break;
    case "topics":
            shClass = TopicsClass;
            break;
}
serializer.Deserialize<shClass>(response);
```

This code does not work, and this just to give you an idea what I need. Is this possible?

I hope you can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: You can't pass a type through a template argument via a variable. Templates are generated at compile time. Depending on the serializer you are using, you might be able to use the `value.GetType()` to deserialize the value.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: It can be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to put it outside the switch?? You can try putting it inside instead

```
switch ((cbxType.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Value)
{
    case "articles":
            serializer.Deserialize<ArticlesClass>(response);
            break;
    case "topics":
            serializer.Deserialize<TopicsClass>(response);
            break;
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to try something different. Your solution was my other option.